# Prove $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ +\ \ln(\sqrt x\ +\sqrt {1+x})}{\sqrt {1-x^2}} dx=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, alternative-proof

***If a simple way exists***, I am looking to show that

$$\boxed{K=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x)+\ln(\sqrt x+\sqrt {1+x})}{\sqrt {1-x^2}} dx=0}$$

say, with  symmetry, a clever change of  variables, or  integrations by parts, ***without evaluating  integrals separately.*** [It is similar to @Zacky question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3490404/proving-that-int-0-pi-fracx-ln1-sin-x-sin-xdx-3-int-0-frac-pi2-fr), of proving $$\boxed{\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{3}-x\right)\frac{\ln(1-\sin x)}{\sin x}dx=0}$$
without calculating separately integrals.

If we  take separately
$$I=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt {1-x^2}}dx,\>\>\>\>J=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(\sqrt x+\sqrt {1+x})}{\sqrt {1-x^2}}dx$$the integrals $I$ and $J$ define the same series to a sign (two series of opposite sums)
$$ I=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{{2n \choose n}}{4^{n}(2n+1)^{2}},\>\>\>\>\>J=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{{2n \choose n}}{4^{n}(2n+1)^{2}}$$

---

**Explanation** [By Fourier series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086005/fourier-series-for-a-logarithm?noredirect=1) $\ln\left(\sqrt{1+\sin x}+\sqrt{\sin x}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2k)!}{4^k(2k+1)(k!)^2}\sin((2k+1)x)$ then $J=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln\left(\sqrt{\sin t}+\sqrt{1+\sin t}\right)dt=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{{2n \choose n}}{4^{n}(2n+1)^{2}}$
$ I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(t)}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}dt$ We know that  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{{2n \choose n}}{4^{n}}t^{2n} $ and $ \int_{0}^{1}\log(t)t^{2n}dt=-\frac{1}{(2n+1)^{2}}$ then $I=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{{2n \choose n}}{4^{n}(2n+1)^{2}} $

---

We can write K as
$$K=\int_0^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} \Big(\ln(\sin t )+\ln\left(\sqrt{\sin t}+\sqrt{1+\sin t}\right)\Big)dt=0 $$

**Remark :** [Wolframalpha can calculate K](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5Bln%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%2Bln%5C%2840%29%5Csqrt%20x%2B%20%5Csqrt%20%5C%2840%291%2Bx%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%2C%5Csqrt%20%5C%2840%291-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%5D), but [do not know how to calculate](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5Bln%5C%2840%29%5Csqrt%20x%2B%20%5Csqrt%20%5C%2840%291%2Bx%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%2C%5Csqrt%20%5C%2840%291-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%5D) $$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(\sqrt x+\sqrt {1+x})}{\sqrt {1-x^2}} dx$$
***I believe that Wolframe uses a simple way to see that $K$  is zero*** . [same observation for the Zacky’s integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5Bpi%2C3%5D%20%20-x%5C%2841%29%20%20Divide%5B%20ln%5C%2840%291-%5Csin%20x%5C%2841%29%2Csin%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2CDivide%5B%5Cpi%2C2%5D%7D%5D)

Comment: For what it's worth, the inverse hyperbolic functions can be seen here

Comment: Yes, I deleted my comment on closer inspection

Comment: Of potential use: numerically, it appears that $\int_0^{1/2}dx\frac{\ln(x)+\ln(\sqrt x + \sqrt{1+x})}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = -\int_{1/2}^1dx\frac{\ln(x)+\ln(\sqrt x + \sqrt{1+x})}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$  _However_ the integrand is _not_ odd about $x=1/2$.

Comment: It's possible you might be right, @Jane.  But my feeling is that that's really a deceptive 0.  I get -1.25594*10^-15 when I numerically integrate the original function.

Comment: From what I see  in **Explanation** your proof answers the question as it was done without calculating separately the integrals ($I$ and $J$ aren't evaluated as their value are never found and only a connection between them is shown), this is also what I am looking for in the post you linked. Are you looking for something else?

Comment: Another way to deal with the $J$ integral is to substitute $x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$, arrive at $J=2\int_0^1 \frac{\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \sqrt{1-t^2}\right)}{1+t^2}dt$ and now to differentiate under the integral sign w.r.t. a after putting $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$. This gives: $$J=\pi \int_0^\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \left(\sqrt 2 -\frac{1}{\sqrt {1-x^2}}
\right)\frac{dx}{1-2x^2}$$ So perhaps one can manipulate this to arrive at $I$. But you might need to clarify if this type of answer is what you're looking for (just a connection between the two integrals without explicit evaluation).

Comment: @Zacky I am looking for **if a simple way exists** to show that $K = 0$ : A symmetry? A change of clever variables ?!, without using  series or another sophisticated method. We can reduce the calculation of $J$ to the calculation of $L=\displaystyle \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\text{arcsinh}\left(\sqrt{\sin t}\right)dt$. The calculation of L is given in [this link][1] 


  [1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086852/closed-form-for-integral-of-inverse-hyperbolic-function-in-terms-of-4f-3?noredirect=1

Comment: @WAH  $\int_0^{1/3}dx\frac{\ln(x)+\ln(\sqrt x + \sqrt{1+x})}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = -\int_{1/3}^1dx\frac{\ln(x)+\ln(\sqrt x + \sqrt{1+x})}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$ U know why ? it's a simple application of Chasle

Answer (score 5):

I know this is not exactly what it is asked for.
On the path of Zacky,

\begin{align*}
 J&=\int_0^1\frac{\text{arcsinh}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx\\
 &\overset{\text{IBP}}=\Big[\arcsin (x)\text{arcsinh}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)\Big]_0^1-\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\arcsin x}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+x}}dx}_{_{z=\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}}}\\
 &=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)-\sqrt{2}\int_0^1 \frac{z\arcsin\left(\frac{1-z^2}{1+z^2}\right)}{(1+z^2)\sqrt{1-z^2}}dz\\
 &=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)-\sqrt{2}\int_0^1 \frac{z\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-2\arctan z\right)}{(1+z^2)\sqrt{1-z^2}}dz\\
 &=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\ln\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)-\sqrt{2}\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{z}{(1+z^2)\sqrt{1-z^2}}dz}_{=\text{K}}\right)+2\sqrt{2}\int_0^1 \frac{z\arctan z}{(1+z^2)\sqrt{1-z^2}}dz\\
 K&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left[\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{1-z^2}}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{1-z^2}}\right)\right]_0^1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\ln\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)\\\
 J&=2\sqrt{2}\int_0^1 \frac{z\arctan z}{(1+z^2)\sqrt{1-z^2}}dz
  \end{align*}
Define on $[0,1]$,
\begin{align*}F(a)&=\int_0^1 \frac{z\arctan (az)}{(1+z^2)\sqrt{1-z^2}}dz\\
F^\prime(a)&=\int_0^1 \frac{z^2}{(1+z^2)(1+a^2z^2)\sqrt{1-z^2}}dz\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{\sqrt{2}\arctan\left(\frac{z\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\right)-\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}\arctan\left(\frac{z\sqrt{1+a^2}}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\right)}{1-a^2}\right]_{z=0}^{z=1}\\
&=\frac{\pi\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{1+a^2}}-1\right)}{2(1-a^2)\sqrt{2}}
\end{align*}
Since $F(0)=0$ then,
\begin{align*}\int_0^1 \frac{z\arctan z}{(1+z^2)\sqrt{1-z^2}}dz&=F(1)-F(0)\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}\int_0^1\frac{\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{1+a^2}}-1\right)}{1-a^2}da\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}\left[\text{arctanh}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}a}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}\right)-\text{arctanh}(a)\right]_0^1\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}\lim_{a\rightarrow 1}\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+a^2}+a\sqrt{2}}{1+a}\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi\ln 2}{4\sqrt{2}}
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}\boxed{J=\frac{\pi\ln 2}{2}}\end{align*}